# Processing Credit card statement using str_match_all in R: how can I skip all alpha characters but capture the number at the end

Tags: r, regex, string, match, stringr

Consider a vector of characters, in R. This is, as you guess, a credit card statement extract (saved in a variable x)

```
[1] "Statement includes payments and charges received by April 20, 2017 May 11, 2017"
[2] "Statement Period From March 21 to April 20, 2017"                               
[3] "At April 20, 2017 250,000.00 175,836.16"                                        
[4] "April 07 PAYMENT RECEIVED."                                                     
[5] "April 07 PAYMENT RECEIVED.THANK YOU 20,000.00"                                  
[6] "March 20 GOOGLE *TRUECALLER G.CO/PAYHELP# 29.00"                                
[7] "April 20 SERVICE TAX (INCL SBC & KKC) 488.51"                                   
[8] "April 20 FINANCE CHARGES 3,256.70"
```

We need to convert this character array into a 3 variable matrix using str_match such that the first column is the Date e.g. `April 07` or `March 20`

The second column should contain the entire text starting from the end of the "date" to the start of the number at the end. All rows without a number at the end can be ignored.

The third column must have the number with the comma and the decimal point included.

I searched a lot but the solutions just skip all initial numbers and only match the last 1 or two digits.

I have tried

```
str_match_all(x,"(April [0-9]{2})(.+)([\\d,\\.]+)$")
```

This matches the first column but the second column also contains the first few digits of the 3rd column (the number) at the end, and the third column contains the last digit only :-(

I am making a fundamental mistake and if this is solved my credit card statement can be easily stored in a matrix.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected output for entry #3 ?

Comment: @StevenBeaupré: the expected output is numeric for entry #3. The solution from Andrew below worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `str_match`, without the `_all` (as there is only one of each item in a row).  Try this...

```
str_match(x,"([A-Z][a-z]+\\s[0-9]{2})([^0-9]+)([0-9,\\.]+$)")
```

or this, if there are lines with numbers as part of the middle section of text...

```
str_match(str_trim(x),"([A-Z][a-z]+\\s[0-9]{2})(.+\\s)([0-9,‌​\\.]+$)")
```

Comment: Thanks, @andrew. This worked. 
PS: I have simplified the question. Actually, there is a list of lists that contain credit card statements' pages. Hence the choice of _str-match-all_

Comment: And I believe you have a point @andrew. I don't need str-match-all. The function without a "_all" works as good. thanks

Comment: we got a bug in the solution you proposed. It does not parse the rows that have numbers in the central (2nd column), e.g.
`"March 20 LINKEDIN-219*4710221 LINKEDIN.COM 6,000.00 "  `
This row was not selected by the proposed regex. Can you suggest a change? Thanks

Comment: Ah. How about `str_match(str_trim(x),"([A-Z][a-z]+\\s[0-9]{2})(.+\\s)([0-9,\\.]+$)")`